# Burninate [webdriverjs]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I edited all questions in [webdriverjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriverjs) which were ambiguous, because webdriverjs may refer to [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver)+[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or [webdriver-io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriver-io) (+[javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)).

There only 18 questions that are left are tagged with [protractor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protractor) which uses [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver), so it is unambiguous now and can be moved in bulk to [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver).

<strike>Is this possible or do I need to retag the rest of them?</strike> I'm retagging them. Hopefully it will vanish and never come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tag [webdriverjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriverjs) is gone.

Comment: ... or not. It's back again.

Comment: It's empty again and will be cleaned up later. If it is resurrected again, the best course of action would be to add it as a synonym for [selenium-webdriver] as is done with other language bindings. The good thing is that now there wasn't even a single [webdriver-io] question.