# Unable to add the webdriverjs tag to a question

Tags: support, tags, tag-synonym-process

I just posted a question, but I was unable to add tag [webdriverjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriverjs).

Question URL: *[WebdriverJS returns undefined instead of size of web elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259602/webdriverjs-returns-undefined-as-function-execute-later)*

I have also added another two tags: [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) and [drop-down-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drop-down-menu)

Question allow me to search a tab and select, but after save I can't see tag [webdriverjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webdriverjs).

Comment: webdriverjs is a synonym of [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selenium-webdriver/synonyms)

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268229/burninate-webdriverjs

Comment: okay. make sense.